# Java SQL Operation Requiring Multiple Sub Operations

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table with 3 columns and approximately 11,000 rows. The first row is an auto-increment primary key, followed by two Integers. These integers are the primary key ID of another table, which has the information I require. (The information I'm looking for is first names).

My plan is to output the necessary information to a standard text file using a FileWriter with each row being represented by one line like this "user1, user2". Once all ~11,000 rows have been fully processed, I would like to print a success message, then terminate the program.

The problem is I don't know the best way to go about retrieving this information in bulk, without it skipping rows. I've also attempted to use a while loop, however have been gotten stuck in the loop, resulting in corruption. Here's my latest attempt, which is terminating before it completing:

```
//Code to get total number of rows in table
//
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    statement1 = connect.createStatement();
    rs1 = statement1.executeQuery("select * from table2 limit (i-1), 1");
    while(rs1.next() {
        int user1 = rs1.get("user1");
        int user2 = rs1.get("user2");
        statement2 = connect.createStatement();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        rs2 = statement2.executeQuery("select * from table1 where id = user1");
        while(rs2.next()) {
            String name = rs2.get("name");
            builder.append(name).append(", ");
        }
        rs3 = statement2.executeQuery("select * from table1 where id = user2");
        while(rs3.next()) {
            String name = rs2.get("name");
            builder.append(name);
        }
    }
    //Code here to write the row to file, ensure empty StringBuilder, and close necessary SQL
}
System.out.println("Successfully processed" + size + " rows!");
System.out.println("Terminating program");
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Why not just fetch everything in one simple query with joins?

Comment: @Durandal Alright so after a bit of research (I didn't know such a thing existed!), it seems like that will cut down on the operations I will have to run. But I still foresee the problem of either a) connection timing out from the database; b) The exit statement being processed before all rows are converted. How can I ensure it will run for all 11,000 rows?

Comment: The problems you "foresee" are a human view, computers do not do stuff randomly. They do exactly as you tell them to do (If its not what you wanted, you told them wrong). Scratch the limit clause and work through the result set. Done.